# jquery animate container to the left half way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I have a container which I am appending some content to (hidden via overflow:hidden). I want to slide the container to the left all the way so it then shows the new content and none of the original content. It's a similar style to image sliders. where the current content slides out one way and the new content slides in the other way all at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would have provided some code, it would be easier to understand the question better. May be I'm wrong but from what I understand, I created a quick example at

http://jsfiddle.net/pXy2C/

Check if it is the thing you needed?